# Can I visit the Jewel mall after checking in my luggage at Changi?

Tags: airports, singapore, check-in, sin

Jewel is the recently opened development project created close to the Changi airport in Singapore.

The last time I visited Jewel was to see the waterfall and I didn't have a flight out of Singapore that time. Now, I have a flight in a few weeks out of Singapore and I wanted to know if I can visit Jewel and shop around a bit after checking in my luggage at the terminal. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be no problem. Terminal 1-3 are [connected via link bridges](http://www.changiairport.com/en/maps.html#18.5/1.3550017/103.9885069/-67) to Jewel so the only thing to consider is how early your check-in opens, this might be only 2 hours before the flight. If you are travelling from terminal 4, this will be harder, as you will have to take a bus there and back.

Alternatively, depending on your airline, you might be able to do an early check-in directly at Jewel. The website of the airport has a [long list of airlines](http://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-guide/departing/checking-in/early-check-in/jeweleci/jeweleciairlines.html) which offer early check in at Jewel up to 3 hours before the flight.

Comment: I didn't know about the Jewel check-in option and it looks like my airline qualifies for this. Awesome!