# Where is this huge indoor waterfall?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

[Link to video](https://twitter.com/i/status/1347688195375431681)

[image]

Given the trains and the shopping mall, I am suspecting an airport ... possibly Singapore, it has been a few  years since I lived there, and things change quickly

[image]

Comment: Related, not duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152122/how-to-visit-jewel-in-changi-on-layover-without-paying-extra https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138040/can-i-visit-the-jewel-mall-after-checking-in-my-luggage-at-changi

Comment: Did you search before asking here? The answer appears multiple times in the top five searches for "singapore indoor waterfall".

Comment: If I knew it were Singapore, then I would not have to ask, or  search

Comment: But you did mention in your question that you *suspected* it might be Singapore. Given that, the search suggested by @BruceWayne seems like a reasonable thing to try.

Comment: Yes, but only because I used to live there & it seemed Singaporeish. But it didn't exist when I left a few years back & I didn't imagine that it could have been built so quickly

Comment: I downvoted for lack of research. I don't understand how to use twitter too well, but even in the link you put to the video someone asks where this is, and someone answers.

Comment: As is your prerogative. I would downvote me too, if I could. I think that I have come to rely on S.E too much :-)

Comment: The trains are the inter-terminal trains - both for the public area and the secure area. One of the trains in the secure area (T2 to 3 I think) passes right by it, though 2 of 4 terminals are currently not in operation since the folks running it are using the  covid period to refurbish those terminals, so not all the trains will be running

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is the **rain vortex** at the Jewel complex, Changi Airport, Singapore.
It is claimed to be the world's tallest indoor waterfall.

Please see [Jewel Changi Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_Changi_Airport)

Please also see [Collected Rainwater Powers the World’s Tallest Indoor Waterfall at Singapore’s Jewel Changi Airport](https://www.thisiscolossal.com/2019/04/jewel-changi-airport-waterfall/)

Comment: Good old Sg ! I was a P.R for almost a decade and still miss it

Answer (score 25):

Don't forget to try [Google Image Search / Lens](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) first. Result searching with your image:

[image]

First result: Changi airport Singapore.

Comment: @Willeke the point of this answer is to use Google.

Comment: Lolx! Franck, we are both active on Software Recommendations, so I ought to know of this. It's just that I am Googlephobic. I much prefer TinEye for reverse image search (embarrassingly, it [found the image](https://tineye.com/search/463409675e871e9754b5bf030bd98375770d5e34?sort=score&order=desc&page=1))  Sorry to have wasted your time :-/

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica no pb, searching for an image is just one right click and one left click on chrome ;) the comments were  aimed at now-deleted willeke comments, not your question.

Comment: Excellent hint.

Comment: So you are going to post such an answer to every similar question and just harvest the fake internet points from fellow haters?

Comment: @VladimirF: Teach a man to fish, and you'll have less boilerplate answers to write on StackExchange.

Comment: @VladimirF Please accept my sincere apologies for writing a useful answer.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I used Tineye before, but since they introduced reCaptcha (by Google) I’m looking for something else.. tips?

Comment: @jornane Bing and other main search engines

Comment: Can't see the point of this answer. Most of us knows how to use google imge search but I wouldn't have learnt about this beautiful indoor waterfall if op had used Google.

Comment: @nnsense we don't want to have one question for each image on google.

Comment: If someone goes that far to understand where is some beautiful spot and they post it here, can't see no harm. It's great to find out new places! :)

Comment: @nnsense I recommend https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn or similar places, better to discover new locations :)

Comment: Teaching people how to use google for this kind of search would have been more helpful, as the other answer added.

Comment: @Willeke I linked to https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en